# Open via android-device localhost on PC

Tags: android, localhost, wifi, connect

Situation: on PC installed server, and available address with this site: `http://localhost`
And installed Connectify Hotspot to share internet via wi-fi.

Also, I have android-device from which I need visit `localhost` on my PC. Via wi-fi is not principal.

How I can do this? I have read a lot of instructions, but they are for AVD (through `10.0.2.2`), that I could do, but not with real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it.

1. Disable `firewall` while you testing connection.
2. Define your `wi-fi` `IP-address` by `ipconfig`.
3. On local server you need to create folder with this `IP-address` and put in this folder site or something, you want to open through `wi-fi` on mobile.

example: `192.168.77.1/www/index.php`

1. Restart your server. After this you will be able to access to your site in PC-browser by your `wi-fi` `IP-address`. If not - restart server another once, or something going wrong :)
2. Turn on mobile `wi-fi` and in browser try to access to `wi-fi` `IP-address`.
   Profit.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` on the device refers to the device itself, not to your computer. Get your computers IP address (`ifconfig` on linux or mac systems) and use this instead of `localhost`.

Comment: I have tried this. ipconfig -> wireless connection -> ipv4-address
And nod32 firewall disabling doesnt help.

Comment: try to access your computer with the device browser first to see if it is blocked somehow. If you can not access it, it's not an android problem, but some configuration problem with your computer of wireless.

Comment: I have tried enter in mobile browser ip of PC wifi - no result. "Error link not found".
By the way, I tried to enter it in PC browser - the same result.
I dont understand, is it blocked or something else. And if it blocked - by what?
If it matters, I can go online on mobile via PC-wifi - nothing blocked.